# Automatically declare variables used in Twig template

Tags: twig, phpstorm

I am refactoring some old twig templates, where many variables are passed to the templates but not declared in doc comments (which also work in PhpStorm for type hinting), like this:

```
{# @var user AppBundle\Entity\User #}
{# @var message string #}
<p>Hello {{ user.fullName }}!</p>
<p>{{ message }}</p>
```

Is there a tool that can pre-generate these doc comments from variables used in a template, ideally usable as PhpStorm plugin?

It will be good enough if it would extract just variable names without types (which are hard to guess from Twig syntax), just for me to make sure that I have not overlooked some variables.

Also, it will be great if it would not declare variables created in the template, like this:

```
{# @var users AppBundle\Entity\User[] #}
{# "user" variable is not documented as it is not passed into the template from outside #}
{% for user in users %}
<p>Hello {{ user.fullName }}!</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Such comments are helpful not only for type hinting, but also for the developer to see what should be passed into the template when refactoring/reusing the template.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you saying that your first code block gives PhpStorm autocomplete for the user object? Asking because mine doesn't do that, and I'd love it to.

Comment: Yes, it works for me (latest PhpStorm and Symfony plugin). Try following exactly this syntax (reversed order of varName/type in compare with phpdoc, always FQCN). But even if it didn't extracting these comments would still be much useful.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there's unfortunately nothing that IDE or available plugins could suggest for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I still hope a positive one will come :)

Comment: so do i :) If there's none - feel free to submit a feature request at PhpStorm bug tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI#newissue=yes

Comment: Good idea, but this will more likely be a feature of the Symfony plugin - I posted it here: https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues/974